# MariaDB to a Zarr Array, how can this be done?

Tags: python, sqlite, mariadb, compression, zarr

Can a MariaDB be used with Zarr or migrated to Zarr in a lossless fashion, if so please provide some guidance on how this can be achieved?

I have searched the Zarr docs and MariaDB docs and did not find enough information on this topic.  I don't want to lose or modify any of the data and I would like to be able to decompress or restore the data to it's original MariaDB state.  I receive output in the form of a 4TB MariaDB (10.2) containing multiple tables of various dimensions and multiple variable types. I am using python (+3.6) and would like to take advantage of Zarr for the purpose of being able to perform exploratory data analysis on the data contained across multiple tables in the MariaDB while it is compressed in an effort to save local disk space.  The storage of the data and processing of the data is all done locally and there is no plan to utilize cloud services.

I have considered converting the MariaDB to a sqlite database with Python but stopped looking into that route as I understand this could lead to a loss/corruption of data.

Thank you advance,
Brian